# LINQ query to group results into an array

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

Given:

```
var detailList = new List<DetailItem>();
```

Where:

```
class DetailItem
{
    string A;
    MyType B;
}
```

Can a LINQ query group on field A into the following data structure:

```
class GroupItem
{
    string A;
    List<MyType> AllBsWithinA;
}



IEnumerable<GroupItem> linqQuery = detailList.SomeLinqMagic(…);
```

The data in question is all memory based so this is a LINQ to Objects question.

Comment: Fields declared like this would be private and thus inaccessible outside the classes themselves. Did you mean to make them public properties?

Comment: @svik - No the freestyle code scripter in me had a chance to play in the absence of the C# compiler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks straightforward, unless I missed your meaning:

```
IEnumerable<GroupItem> linqQuery = detailList
    .GroupBy(i => i.A)
    .Select(g => new GroupItem() 
    { 
        A = g.Key, 
        AllBsWithinA = g.Select(i => i.B).ToList() 
    });
```

Comment: Nothing missed my question was that straight forward. I will try out your example and hopefully give this answer a green tick later, thanks.